# Creating Repo From Template Owned By Different Organization using CURL

Tags: curl, github-api

The following command is only able to create the repo from template when`TEMPLATE_OWNER` is the same as `REPO_OWNER`. Otherwise it fails with the message `Resource not accessible by personal access token`

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer new_repo_organization_token" \
-H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
-d '{
  "owner": "REPO_OWNER",
  "name": "repo",
  "description": "render"
}' \
"https://api.github.com/repos/TEMPLATE_OWNER/TEMPLATE_REPO/generate"
```

The template repo is public. Could this be a configuration issue in the template repo?